# what is the pythonic way to processs "\n" in line of a file

Tags: python

what is the pythonic way to processs "\n" in line of a file

> readline or readlines or replace '\n' by myself

example file(t.txt):

```
221.177.0.0/16  
117.128.0.0/21  
221.183.0.0/16
```

when i use the code below read the file(t.py):

```
import sys
fn = sys.argv[1]
lines = list()
with open(fn) as f:
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line)
print lines
```

when run script code, i get this output:

```
python t.py t.txt 
['221.177.0.0/16\n', '117.128.0.0/21\n', '221.183.0.0/16\n']
```

there many "\n" in list.

Comment: lines.append(line.strip('\n'))

Answer (score 2):

Strip it off when processing the file.

```
>>> '221.177.0.0/16\n'.rstrip('\n')
'221.177.0.0/16'
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can remove the last '\n' with

```
    lines.append(line[:-1])
```

here '\n' is considered as a single character so line[:-1] would remove the trailing **ONE** character from "line"

Answer (score 0):

Just use `rstrip` in a `readlines` loop. For example:

```
import sys
fn = sys.argv[1]
f = open(fn)
lines = [l.rstrip() for l in f.readlines()]
f.close()
```